# "There is no no-color option ("less --help" for help)" LESS

Tags: css, macos, less, phpstorm

I've been using less for front-end development but i'm getting this error last couple days.

I'm using PhpStorm's watchers to compile less files to css files. But when i edited the less file, the compiler adds this line to top of css file and the css file doesn't work anymore.

Also it doesnt even compile the less file;
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's not adding the text to my css file but it doesn't compile at the same time :/
http://i.imgur.com/icODcTr.png

Comment: 1) What is your less version? Is it installed as a npm package or some other way? 2) Please change `Show Console` to "Always" and check what the actual command would be. 3) Try altering your File Watcher: "Arguments" = `$FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css` and uncheck "Create output file from stdout" option -- any better?

Comment: 1) less 436 it says when i type 'less -V'
2) I did
3) I did

Comment: What do you mean by "436"? I have 2.5.3 on my computer .. and it looks to be the latest one (http://lesscss.org/) unless I'm missing something...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xKExG5h.png
and the result after all is;
main.min.css: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: You seems to be using some [completely different program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/less.htm). The proper command should be `lessc` and not just `less`.

Comment: when i edit it to lessc it doesnt let me to apply changes. http://i.imgur.com/mIjAhCa.png

Comment: 1) Because you do not have less compiler installed 2) Once installed it may be located in different folder (I'm a Windows user and cannot tell exact location for your Mac)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper name for [LESS compiler](http://lesscss.org/#getting-started) is `lessc` which is installed as npm package (`npm install -g less`). It is written in JavaScript and requires nodejs to run.

The `less` command you are using seems to be the [standard Linux/Unix "less" command](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/less.htm).

Comment: Clearly access right error (not enough permission). Run as root maybe (as suggested in error output)? Whatever the reason is -- those are official instructions from LESS website.

Comment: Thank you bro. I've changed the compiler from to /usr/bin/less /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc and its working now.